# Basic JS - Is this function okay?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a carousel (Owl Carousel) with vertically centered controls. Because of the structure, I have to absolutely position the previous and next arrow. Because the page is responsive, their position is dynamic. The size of the controls may also change.

[image: My carousel.]

I've written a function that runs on load and resize. It gets the height of the image and the height of the controls, subtracts the latter from the former, divides by two, and then uses that number as the controls' margin-top.

It works, but I'm questioning if I'm getting and using all the variables correctly. Does JavaScript read in order? Where it runs the first line, then the next, then the next... I'm strong in CSS but JS has always been a crutch.

Can I write this more efficiently?

```js
function centerCarouselControls() {
  var carouselImage = $('.carousel-card > img');
  var carouselControls = $('.owl-nav > div');
  var carouselHeight = carouselImage.outerHeight();
  var controlHeight = carouselControls.outerHeight();
  var controlMargin = (carouselHeight - controlHeight) / 2;
  carouselControls.css('margin-top', controlMargin);
}

$('.carousel-card > img').load(centerCarouselControls);
$(window).on('resize', centerCarouselControls);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I feel like this might be the type of question that gets flagged on here for not being specific enough. If that's the case, could someone please point me to a community where this would be more appropriate? Thanks!

Comment: Since the code works but you just want someone to review it, I would post on codereview.stackexchange. This site is mostly if you have a bug you can't figure out.

Comment: Awesome, thank you @takendarkk

Comment: JavaScript is executed in sequence, however, there is syntax that can cause that sequence to be altered. However, with your code in `centerCarouselControls` that is not the case.

Comment: CSS can do this for you. Look at solutions leveraging a negative 50% translation.

Comment: "Can I write this more efficiently?" questions should be moved to [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @isherwood I believe it, but played with the CSS long enough that I moved on to JS. The container includes the caption box below the image, which is flexible, as well as 10px of padding above the image, so it's not as simple as using a 50% translation. Too many moving parts, and I can't change the structure of the HTML.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it needs migrating to: codereview.stackexchange

Answer (score 0):

In some browsers your code works like firefox 51, but it is more complete code this:

```
carouselControls.css('margin-top', controlMargin + 'px');
```